# jenkins running multiple build for one github pull request

Tags: github, jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I am using multibranch pipeline plugin in jenkins. I have configured with github setup of our corp. The pipeline reads for events as:

`refspec = +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`

Now, for every pull request, it generates two builds

`pr/1/head
pr/1/merge`

Why do it generates two jobs or I should say github is generating two events as above. The Pull request reamined in open state though.

Answer (score 0):

**pr/1/head** is the HEAD commit of the branch that is requested to be merged.

**pr/1/merge** is the result of the requested merge.

Both match the wildcard in your refspec, thus both build.  It is possible (but generally rare) for a branch to build, have no merge conflicts, but for the resulting merge to fail the build making `pr/1/merge` useful.